# What's the difference between keys(), values(), entries() and Symbol.iterator?

Tags: javascript, object, iterator

There are iterable and non-iterable objects in JS. If the object contains `Symbol.iterator()` function then it's iterable. If the object doesn't contain this function, then it's non-iterable. Why? This function returns iterator object.

[The source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator#:%7E:text=The%20well%2Dknown%20Symbol.iterator%20symbol%20specifies%20the%20default%20iterator%20for%20an%20object.%20Used%20by%20for...of.)

> The well-known Symbol.iterator symbol specifies the default iterator for an object. Used by for...of.

It's okay. But there are other functions: `keys()`, `values()`, `entries()`. These functions return iterator too. What's the difference between these methods and function `Symbol.iterator()`?

It turns out that both of these method are in prototype.

[image]

**So, what the difference between `keys()`, `values()`, `entries()` and `Symbol.iterator()`?** Looks like they both return iterator objects.

Comment: `keys()` etc return _an_ iterator, not "the" iterator. You can have any number of methods returning different iterators.

Comment: They return iterators over different things! Have you tried them? `[Symbol.iterator]` just returns the "default" iterator (which, in the case of a `Map`, is the `entries` one, but it's different for other collections)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properties like `entries`, `keys`, and `values` are there for convenience. They allow easy iteration over the content of the Map instance. Note also from the image you posted that `entries` is also the value of the `Symbol.iterator` property.

The `Symbol.iterator` property is present so that code like

```
for (entry of someMap)
```

will behave the same as

```
for (entry of someMap.entries())
```

The `.keys()` and `.values()` methods allow iterating over one part of the Map instance or the other, in situations where you only care about the keys, or only about the values. Clearly `.entries()` would allow that as well, via deconstructing assignment or simple array indexing.

Ultimately, there are often no satisfactory fundamental answers to questions like "why does language x do this?" or "why does API x do this?" because they're things designed by people who had their own reasons.

Comment: By the way, I was trying to call one of these methods with `prototype`. But I can't, there's just an error. Why? For example, `values()` is in prototype of an instance. Why can't I call this method like `map.prototype.values()`? [Here is my example](https://jsfiddle.net/fkpwmx1s/)

Comment: Because that's not how prototype methods work. It's just `map.values()`.

Comment: @Ivan You can call the prototype method but you need to use .call like this: Map.prototype.values.call(myMap) In fact if you wanted to test if a value is a map or not this is how you do it: Map.prototype.has.call(testValue);// this will throw if testValue is not an ES6 map.